# Excecutable file command not found

Tags: command-line

I have been trying to install a tool called MetaACE. I have included the command line below.

```
deebak@ubuntu:~$ cd Downloads/MetaACE_LTD
deebak@ubuntu:~/Downloads/MetaACE_LTD$ bash
deebak@ubuntu:~/Downloads/MetaACE_LTD$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
deebak@ubuntu:~/Downloads/MetaACE_LTD$ ls
bin  docs  Example  metaace.bash  metaace.bash~  runtime
deebak@ubuntu:~/Downloads/MetaACE_LTD$ source metaace.bash
deebak@ubuntu:~/Downloads/MetaACE_LTD$ cat metaace.bash
#!/bin/bash
METAACE=/home/deebak/Downloads/MetaACE_LTD
RUNTIME_PATH=$METAACE/runtime/v84
PATH=/bin:$PATH
export PATH
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:${RUNTIME_PATH}/runtime/glnxa64:${METAACE}/bin:${RUNTIME_PATH}/bin/glnxa64:${RUNTIME_PATH}/sys/os/glnxa64:${RUNTIME_PATH}/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64/server
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH

XAPPLRESDIR=/home/mathewsn/MetaACE_LTD/runtime/v84/X11/app-defaults
export XAPPLRESDIR

deebak@ubuntu:~/Downloads/MetaACE_LTD$ cd bin
deebak@ubuntu:~/Downloads/MetaACE_LTD/bin$ ls -l
total 916
-rw-r--r-- 1 deebak deebak     51 Sep 26  2014 cpmetafiles
-rwxr-xr-x 1 deebak deebak      0 Mar  1 15:48 metaace
-rw-r--r-- 1 deebak deebak 338498 Apr 27  2015 metaace.bak
-rw-r--r-- 1 deebak deebak    206 Apr  7 14:58 MetaACE.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 deebak deebak   1271 Mar 31 10:32 MetaACElog.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 deebak deebak 338498 Apr 27  2015 MetaACE_LTD
-rw-r--r-- 1 deebak deebak 239484 Jan  9  2015 MetaACE_LTDo
-rw-r--r-- 1 deebak deebak    282 Mar 31 10:32 runData.mat

deebak@ubuntu:~/Downloads/MetaACE_LTD/bin$ metaace
/usr/bin/python: /home/deebak/Downloads/MetaACE_LTD/runtime/v84/bin/glnxa64/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by /usr/bin/python)
/usr/bin/python: /home/deebak/Downloads/MetaACE_LTD/runtime/v84/bin/glnxa64/libssl.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by /usr/bin/python)
**metaace: command not found**
deebak@ubuntu:~/Downloads/MetaACE_LTD/bin$
```

How do i execute this bin file? 
Or is there any other question to which i can link this problem to?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You have probably have the executable in a folder which is not searched for executables. I do not know MetaACE and how it works.

Verify:
env | grep PATH

Either:
1) add folder for executable to PATH.
PATH=~/Downloads/MetaACE_LTD/bin:$PATH
(metaace.bash assume executable is placed in /bin)

2) add active folder to PATH (This is dangerous in case one should get executables in download folders, copy files, etc. Normally not done in PRODuction environment.)
You then need to have ~/Downloads/MetaACE_LTD/bin as active folder in order to start executable, like you example.

3) start binary by using complete path and file:
~/Downloads/MetaACE_LTD/bin/metaace
One might in general run into additiopnal problem with other executables, but MetaACE seems to only have one.

4) install/move/copy MetaACE in other folders.

5) make softlink for execuble in a folder used by PATH to where you have it.